# How do I set a variable with a number to an html form input value attribute

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to set a numeric value to an html form's input value attribute as a variable. I'm aware that the value attribute implicitly converts to a string. How can I get the variable to be read before it is converted to a string?

`<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="" id="amount">`

This is the input whose value I want to set.

`document.getElementById("amount").setAttribute('value', this.amount)`

This is one method I've been trying.

Comment: What is the use case of this ? What do you want to achieve ? You can use `<input type="number" id="amount" hidden name="amount" :value="this.amount">`

Comment: I have a hidden form that is supposed to be submitted to a payment platform

Comment: You can try this `<input type="number" id="amount" hidden name="amount" :value="this.amount">`

Comment: @RohitJindal it turns out the error was elsewhere in my code. But your method helped me discover it. Thanks mate

Comment: I added an answer with a demo, Hope that will work to understand in better way.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm aware that the value attribute implicitly converts to a string.*

It's not correct, It will return number only if you are assigning numeric value into a `:value` attribute.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    productName: 'xyz',
    amount: 10
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      console.log(this.productName, typeof this.productName)
        console.log(this.amount, typeof this.amount)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" :value="productName">
  <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" :value="amount">
  <button @click="submitForm">Submit</button>
</div>
```

You can see the return data type in the console on click of `submit`.